# How Can I Test an Error Boundary In Production?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

I'm adding a top-level error boundary to my app.  Everything appears fine locally but I'm not sure how to go about testing it in production, as I don't know of any render errors.  Is there a way to force a react component to throw an error in the wild?  Or is there a better way to ensure an error boundary does what it should do without a real error present?

Answer (score 2):

To enforce a ErrorBoundary to be triggered just throw an error in a child-component
using the standard Error-throw: `throw new Error("Something went wrong")`
If you want to have the error only in production you could check if "NODE_ENV" is set to "production" and only throw the error then.